# char* memory allocation error unless with 'top -b -n 1'

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am running a C code that needs the number of steps in an MD trajectory file. It first calls a function which gets the number of steps.

The function call is

```
int steps=get_steps(argv[2]);
```

and the function itself (in a separate header file) is

```
int get_steps(char* f){
  printf("file_len function call\n");
  char *cmd=malloc(sizeof(char)*120);
  printf("%p",cmd);
  printf("created command");
  sprintf(cmd,"wc -l %s > lines.txt",f);
  system(cmd);
  printf("called system command");
  FILE *f1;
  f1=fopen("lines.txt","r");
  int steps;
  fscanf(f1,"%d",&steps);
  fclose(f1);
  f1=fopen(f,"r");
  int atoms;
  fscanf(f1,"%d",&atoms);
  fclose(f1);
  sprintf(cmd,"rm lines.txt");
  system(cmd);
  free(cmd);
  return (int)steps/(atoms+2);
}
```

I am in the process of editing this code so that it takes fewer input parameters from argc, and when I compiled and tested the code, it crashed at this point because of a segmentation fault.

However, when I run the code with

```
./migration_binding Na200_Mg10 traj.xyz top -b -n 1
```

it works fine. Any hints on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: and the return for `malloc` (which can simply be `malloc (120)`, because `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, David. fopen and fscanf are successful if I run them both before and after the line where I malloc char* cmd. However, now the program crashes when I use fclose(f2) (where f2 is the result of fopen("traj.xyz","r");) after malloc'ing cmd.

Answer (score 0):

If you're accessing the second argument: `argv[2]`, you need to execute the program with at least 2 arguments. Otherwise it will try to read memory that is not yours, which usually ends with a segmentation fault.

You can also check the length of the `argv` array - that is the first main-function parameter:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

*Note that the first argument is always the path to the executable file.*

Comment: I call the program with the arguments 'Na200_Mg10' and 'traj.xyz', which are argv[1] and argv[2], which I've double checked is correct. I'm sure this is not the problem because I've also tried putting "traj.xyz" (which exists in the program's directory) into the input of get_steps() and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

So on a whim, I commented out the lines in main() after the function call. It turns out I was using char*s (labels for output files like "_junction_location.dat" and "_ion_timeseries.dat" to put after argv[1]) that I hadn't malloc'ed.

However, my question still stands as related to imperative programming. These errors are the cause of code which is executed AFTER where the program was crashing before. Why would the program crash at get_steps() function call rather than where the errors really were?

Comment: undefined behaviour is undefined